# Getting a DataSouce from url and driver

Tags: java, url, jboss, datasource, driver

I need to initialize a DataSource given url and driver.
Its need to be generic enough to support Oracle and SQL Server.
the app is running on jboss 5.

provided sample for both:

```
<db-connection name="TEST-ORACLE">
<url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@test:1521:ins1</url>
<driver>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</driver>
<user>user</user>
<password>{ENCR}oRloKFKlqXs=</password>
<min-size>5</min-size>
<max-size>30</max-size>
<idle-timeout-minutes>1</idle-timeout-minutes>
</db-connection>

<db-connections>
    <db-connection name="TEST-MSSQLSERVER">
    <url>jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://server:1433/db;ProgramName=program;SelectMethod=cursor;useLOBs=false</url>
    <driver>net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</driver>
    <user>user</user>
    <password>{ENCR}oRloKFKlqXs=</password>
    <min-size>40</min-size>
    <max-size>80</max-size>
    <idle-timeout-minutes>1</idle-timeout-minutes>
</db-connection>
```

The OracleXADataSource is implementing the inteface DataSource so its quit easy... but im not sure that generic enough.

**EDIT**

I wonder what should be the way to achive that if i have multipile db connections and multipile instances / schemas in those connections.....

my current code looks like:

```
private DataSource getDataSourceForTanent(TenantConfig i_Tenant) {
        DataSource result = null;
        ClassLoader loader = DBConnector.class.getClassLoader();
        try {
            Class driverClass = loader.loadClass(i_Tenant.getDriver());
            Object driver = driverClass.newInstance();
            if(driver instanceof OracleDataSource){
                ((OracleDataSource)driver).setURL(i_Tenant.getUrl());
                ((OracleDataSource)driver).setUser(i_Tenant.getUser());
                ((OracleDataSource)driver).setPassword(i_Tenant.getPassword());
                result = (DataSource) driver;
            } else if(driver instanceof Driver){
                Properties prop = new Properties();
                prop.put("user", i_Tenant.getUser());
                prop.put("password", i_Tenant.getPassword());
                prop.put("min-size", i_Tenant.getMinSize());
                prop.put("max-size", i_Tenant.getMaxSize());
                prop.put("idle-timeout-minutes", i_Tenant.getIdleTimeoutMinute());
                Connection con = ((Driver)driver).connect(i_Tenant.getUrl(), prop);
                if(con != null){
                    //TODO: SQLServer handling
                }
            }

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

TenantConfig is a java bean holding the xml properties.

Comment: What exactly are you asking here? JBoss is responsible to give you a DataSource, provided you tell it what the JDBC driver class is. You don't have to care about anything.

Comment: I have multipile db connected, and i need to get a datasource given the db-connection name. using that xml file, which configure all db connected.

Comment: @JBNizet i hope i mannage to make my question a bit clearer

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generic code snippet to get a DataSource by JNDI name:

```
Context initContext = new InitialContext();
Context envContext  = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
DataSource ds = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/mydatasource");
```

But from your XML file I am not sure what the JNDI name is. What XML dialect is it?

Comment: @Noam: So what? That's the standard way to get a DataSource in a JEE app. The JEE server is responsible to return a DataSource based on its configuration.

Comment: @Noam: Actually copy-pasted from JBoss'es website. Surprise: This is the correct thing to do and all decent websites post it that way.

Comment: @KasperSørensen Dont get insulted its just isnt what i was asking and that code u posted isnt the solution for my issue...

Comment: @Noam: application servers are useful because they handle connection pools and datasources for you. You should not reimplement this based on proprietary XML properties. Declare each datasource in JBoss like JBoss documents it, and use JNDI to get the appropriate one depending on your tenant.